# mysql select top 10 of IDs by time period

Tags: mysql, time, diff

Here is the table:

| Id | time |
| --- | --- |
| QQa | 2020-11-04 10:00:10 |
| QQa | 2020-11-05 20:17:04 |
| QQa | 2020-10-08 13:27:01 |
| WWs | 2020-10-09 14:08:44 |
| WWs | 2020-10-09 13:07:46 |
| WWs | 2020-10-09 13:26:57 |
| RRe | 2020-10-08 13:06:39 |

I'm trying to sort/get top 10 of such table by time diff. Here is the output I need (in days):

| ID | Days |
| --- | --- |
| QQa | 4 |
| WWS | 1 |
| RRe | 1 |

and so on...

So QQa took ~4 days others have timestamps within one day.
I'm trying to do it by something like this:

SELECT id, Min(time)
AS `In Time`, Max(time)
AS `Out Time`,
DATEDIFF(Max(time), Min(time))
AS `Time Diff`
FROM database.table GROUP BY id, DATE(time)
ORDER BY `Time Diff` ASC;

I'm afraid I'm not successful in what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated.

upd. https://stackoverflow.com/users/816613/nick-maroulis answer is the query I need. Thank you!

select ID,   datediff( max(time), min(time) ) `Days`
from `table`
group by id
order by `Days` desc
limit 10

Comment: Why do you `GROUP BY DATE(create_date)`? Isn't that the thing you want to know the `MIN()` and `MAX()` of? If so it should not split the result into groups.

Comment: is that output based on the data provided? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55201c/17